# Find the Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform

Could anyone enlighten me on how to find the Laplace Transform of

$$\frac{1-\cos (t)}{t}$$

Comment: so which part of the Laplace Transform is most troubling?

Comment: Well I tried breaking it up but could not find a form for which I have the formulas for. I'm kind of stumped...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Set $$f(t):=\frac{1-\cos t}{t}.$$ We have 
$$\mathcal{L}\{1-\cos t \}(s)=\mathcal{L} \{tf(t) \}(s)=-F'(s), $$
where $F(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $f(t)$.

Comment: Might be stupid of me to ask, but why is it equal to $-F'(s)$?

Comment: @KevinZ by the [General frequency domain differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems).

Comment: Oh! Is that the one where it is equal to $(-1)^1 \times \frac{dF}{ds}$ ?

Comment: @KevinZ indeed.

Comment: Is this correct?

$$-F'(s) = \frac{1}{s} - \frac{s}{s^2+1}$$

Integrating both sides:

$$-F(s) = \ln(s) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(s^2+1)$$
$$-F(s) = \ln( \frac{s}{{\sqrt{s^2+1}}}) + c $$

Since $\lim_{s\to\infty} F(s) = 0$
$\implies$ $0 = \ln(1) + c$ $\implies c = 0$

Thus $F(s) = -\ln( \frac{s}{{\sqrt{s^2+1}}})$

Comment: @Kevin I think so.

Comment: May I ask you what strategy I should adopt for these types of questions? If I am faced with sin and cosines in forms not given by regular transform tables, how should I proceed?

Comment: @KevinZ try looking for the simple pieces that you know how to transform, and use the table of properties to reduce the expression to such pieces.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(t)=\frac{g(t)}{t}=\frac{1-\cos t}{t}
$$
thus the Laplace transform is
$$
  F(s)=\int_s^\infty G(z)\,\mathrm dz=\int_s^\infty \left[\frac{1}{z}-\frac{z}{z^2+1}\right]\,\mathrm dz=\left[\log{z}-\log\left(\sqrt{z^2+1}\right)\right]_s^\infty=\log\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{s^2+1}}{s}\right)
$$